# customizing jackrabbit authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, authorization, jackrabbit

I already have an existing user base (user, roles,user_roles table in database). How could I create custom authentication and authorization module to use this to interact with Jackrabbit repository which is file system transient repository.

I can create a custom login module extending the AbstractLoginModule but principal, usermanager, userimpl etc how will I get these?

User, Roles etc are nodes in repository so how can I use my user base from data base to create access control based nodes and files ?

Will I able able to achieve this at all?

Answer (score 0):

[This is JAAS authentication and Authorizations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html).
You can take a look in [https://github.com/ehsavoie/Silverpeas-Core/tree/master/lib-core/src/main/java/com/stratelia/webactiv/jaas where we did ourown implementation](https://github.com/ehsavoie/Silverpeas-Core/tree/master/lib-core/src/main/java/com/stratelia/webactiv/jaas%20where%20we%20did%20ourown%20implementation).